# clustering with a subgroup

Tags: excel, graph

I am trying to make a clustered plot. The plot should be clustered as follows: three groups for *land use* type and within those groups there should be two bars showing: 1 for *within* natura2000 and 1 for not, with *richness* on the y-axis.

I've seen tons of examples but they all have their data organised differently and don't use two character-variables. Excel gives me a plot with  six bars that is ungrouped when I use 2D clustered column.

my data

```
Land use            Within natura 2000  Richness
Coniferous forest   yes                 0,922216
Coniferous forest   no                  0,841861
Deciduous forest    yes                 1,279474
Deciduous forest    no                  1,146727
Grass               yes                 0,399841
Grass               no                  0,305253
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [Pivot Table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx) and [Pivot Chart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/create-a-pivotchart-HA102919712.aspx) for this.

1. Under insert click Pivot Table and select your data then click okay.
2. Under Pivot Table options select Pivot Chart, for the chart type I used Clustered Column.
3. Check off all three available fields within the pivot table field list.
4. Move Land use to Axis fields, Within natura 2000 to Legend Fields, and Richness to Values (it will probably become Sum of Richness, this is okay).

You can then design the chart to look how you want!